# Why is my archive.php redirecting to front-page.php?

Tags: archives, frontpage

I generate archives using `wp_get_archives()` and get list of all my archives.
But when I click one of the links its always redirect me to `front-page.php` which is `www.mydomainexample.com`.

I've created an `archive.php` file in my directory in case you are wondering. I also saved changes for permalinks.

In my case I want to redirect to year/date. The links that `wp_get_archives()` generate already what I'm looking for `www.mydomainexample.com/2020/12` but it always redirect to my homepage `www.mydomainexample.com`.

What am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean you get redirected to front-page.php. You never access templates directory. Do you mean you’re being redirected to the homepage?

Comment: Yep that's what I mean Jacob. Sorry if it wasn't clear enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, this is on me. My SEO plugin by default disable the archives date and redirect to homepage.

Leave it on here for the people maybe get stumbled by this problem.